# Why do I get an infinite loop created by a subtraction in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, c#

Does anyone have a solution to this ?
When I do the subtraction , it makes a loop that does not stop.

```
  if ((lamp.activeSelf == true)&&(test == true)) 
    {
            money = money - 50;  // <---- This is the problem
            test = false;   
    }
```

Comment: There doesn't look to be a loop going on here, this is just an If statement? Where is this held? Is it in the Update method? Could you post the full code please to help us understand the problem better?

Comment: moreover is useless to explicitly compare a boolean with "true", just use `lamp.activeSelf && test`

Comment: Could you tell how did you find that there's a infinite loop? Does money continue to be subtracted? You can monitor money and test vars using debug.log() to see what  is happening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no loop.

Comment: Usually an infinite loop in Unity will manifest as the editor/player hanging, which the user doesn't mention, so I'd suspect what they mean is that the regular old game loop is continuing to trigger this code on many consecutive frames, without being stopped by `test` — suggesting that some code elsewhere is resetting `test` to true. Could also be that this is inside a setter for `money` itself (or a method called by that setter) so subtracting from money triggers a recursive call sequence. There'd still need to be something resetting `test`. We'll need to see more code & symptoms to diagnose.